# PublishingPage.Description: is there a pendant for Documents in Document Library?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I use the Description property of PublishingPages (located in the pages library of a website) to display information about a page.

Is there a pendant for a document (located in the documents library of a website), which a user can edit? 
Or do I have to define my own site column, named "document description", to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Document' content type have by default "Title" and "Name" Columns only. You need to add a site column for description. A document, in general, is represented by *SPFile* object. So you can use  SPFile.Item["document description"] to get the description of the document in code.